# uvcvideo is loaded but /dev/video0 doesn't exist

Tags: drivers, kernel, webcam, uvc

My webcam worked like a charm until I ran a simple python code to take photo. I ran it with root permission by `sudo python myapp.py`. The program crashed. Then I ran `sudo killall -9 python`.

From that time, I lost my webcam. If I run my program, I get this error: `VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device`. Cheese cann't find device as well.

I google my issue and I find some pages saying that I should re-enable uvcvideo module. I've done it by `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo` but the problem isn't solved.

This is the result of some of my commands:

```
$ lsmod | grep uvc
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              184320  3             
videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo

$ sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

I should also notice that if I restart the computer I get nothing from `lsmod | grep uvc` until I run `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` again.

How should I solve the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue Ubuntu 18.04.1, the `udo modprobe uvcvideo` does not survive a restart when I issue `lsmod | grep uvc`. A solution is needed, please.

Comment: + 1 - same issue with a uvc HDMI capture stick. Worked great for a few days but then after a crash, can't be seen at all. Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I found there is a file called `uvcvideo-blacklist.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d`. It will prevent `uvcvideo` module to be loaded automatically when booting. Commented out the only line "blacklist uvcvideo" in this file will get uvcvideo been automatically loaded at start up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not running a virtual machine with the USB device attached.  In that case you'll see the /dev/bus/usb device but no /dev/video device.